# Programming Akka in Java and sbt dependencies

Tags: java, akka, akka-remoting

I am learning Akka and am trying out Akka remoting. I am using the intellij IDE and the language being used is Java. I tried running the AKKA remote example (Calculator). I am not using the sbt tool. How do I build the application and run it. I tried running the example, but I dont think it is reading the configuration files correctly and is not creating a remote actor. I have included the akka jar files in the project. I have created a simple java project in intellij to run the program.

Am I doing it the right way?. What are the alternate ways to build and run the same. How to use sbt with Java.

Comment: Sbt is primarily aimed at Scala projects. Maven or Gradle can get those same exact dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Dependencies.scala and Versions.scala under project folder; which again you can use with build.sbt.

build.sbt is very similar to build.xml with maven. You can define libraryDependencies and assembly file name, etc.

For example you can refer https://github.com/asethia/akka-streaming-graph/tree/master/project in detail.

Comment: That link is to a Scala project, though, where the question asked how to use sbt with Java